# как остановить аудио?

Tags: python, python-3.x, playsound

Сделал некий таймер. Надо чтобы про нажатии на клавишу аудио переставало воспроизводится. Или просто останавливалась функция. Это только часть всего кода.

```
import time
from playsound import playsound
import msvcrt
# timer
    elif ord(pressedKey) == ord("j"):
        print("Таймер запущен.")
        inputtext = str(input("Напишите о чем вам напомнить: "))
        inputtime = float(input("Через сколько минут?: "))
        inputtime = inputtime * 60
        time.sleep(inputtime)
        print(inputtext)
        def playmusic():
            playsound("music.mp3")
            
        playmusic()
```

Также пробовал как то закрывать функцию с помощью return, но она не закрывалась(

Comment: Попробуйте PyQt5, там есть классы для воспроизведения и контролирования, но, возможно, он будет немного излишним. Можно посмотреть на эти классы: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#details и https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html#details

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел [в реализацию playsound.playsound](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/907f1fe73375a2156f7e0900c4b42c0a60fa1d00/playsound.py#L4) и там нет возможности контролировать работу через код.

И у вас не получилось бы закрыть функцию через `return`, т.к. при воспроизведении музыки вызывался `sleep`, который останавливал работу текущего потока, за это отвечает атрибут `block=True` в функции `playsound`.

Вы можете убрать `sleep`, но не думаю, что это остановит музыку при выходе из функции:

```
playsound("music.mp3", block=False)
```